# Read file from Internal Storage Android

Tags: java, android, filereader

I don't know why I am not able to read file from Internal storage

The code is giving error:

```
public String readFile()
{
    try
    {
        String filePath = MainActivity.this.getFilesDir() + "/"+"Contacts"+"/" + "Contacts";
        File file = new File( filePath );
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        reader.read(jsonString);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        String importError = e.getMessage();
    }
    return jsonString;
}
```

The error is at `reader read (jsonString)` which is saying `can not resolve method read(java.lang.String)`

Comment: I think your file path is wrong.

Comment: The issue with your code is the following:
You feed in java.lang.String to the method FileReader.read(), which expects a char[] primitive data type, as FileReader just inherits that method from the Reader abstract class. Read the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read(char[])

Comment: yes? there is no such method, I don't understand what else you need?

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM:**

Error tells you what is wrong:

> can not resolve method `read(java.lang.String)`

---

**CAUSE:**

[`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) inherits the `read` method from Reader, **in [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) you can find, for example [`Reader.read(CharBuffer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28java.nio.CharBuffer%29), or `Reader.read(char[])` but not `Reader.read(String)`.**

```
public int read(char[] cbuf) throws IOException
```

> Attempts to read characters into the specified character buffer. The buffer is used as a repository of characters as-is: the only changes made are the results of a put operation. No flipping or rewinding of the buffer is performed.

---

**SOLUTION:**

To solve your problem, just convert `jsonString` to `CharBuffer` or `char[]`, for example:

```
char cbuf[] = jsonString.toCharArray();
reader.read(cbuf);
```

---

**ADD-ON's:**

Available `Read.read()` methods:

```
public int read(CharBuffer target) throws IOException
public int read(char[] cbuf) throws IOException
public abstract int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException
```

Comment: Please take a look at this link for documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read(char[])

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I think this answer will not only solve the OP's issue, but will also tell how to look and solve similar issues in the future.

Comment: downvoted because: `toCharArray` returns a new char[]. You are not referencing it anywhere, therefore whatever is put in it is lost.

Comment: @JordiCastilla read again. `toCharArray returns a new char[]`

Answer (score 0):

This is part of code of my last app if you want to read from assets
File location: /assets

```
    try {
        InputStream input = context.getAssets().open(file_name);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();
        data_file = new String(buffer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("File err", "-----" + e.getMessage().toString());
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

**Edit:**
Why you get the error is because you haven't declared the jsonString(Which needs to be a charbuffer)

```
public String readFile()
{
    //Create Charbuffer to save file in
    CharBuffer buffer = null;

    try
    {
        String filePath = MainActivity.this.getFilesDir() + "/"+"Contacts"+"/" + "Contacts";

        File file = new File(filePath);

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);

        reader.read(buffer);
        return buffer.toString();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        String importError = e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: FileReader.read() still does not take in java.lang.String, but an array of characters. Even if the jsonString would have been declared and initialized, it would still have thrown that error: can not resolve method read(java.lang.String)

Comment: how can you say error is because variable is not declared when it clearly says: *can not resolve **method*** in this line: `reader.read(jsonString);`???? the only method in this line is `read`....

Comment: this results in obvious NPE.

Comment: `CharBuffer buffer = null;` -> `reader.read(buffer);` throws NPE. I should have been more specific.